# How to modify node output on node view in Drupal programmatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am familiar with Contemplate module, and also the option of having node.tpl files.

But, how could I alter node content via node api programmatically? I would like to add some custom HTML. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are looking for [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) functionality which provides possibility to add additional content along with node content.

ex; adds a variable to node which is also available to display in node template

```
function test_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
    switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
        $node->content['var1'] ='<div>test value</div>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make a custom module (to implement hook_nodeapi), you may also consider overriding [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6) in your theme's template.php file.  Just rename this function to yourthemename_preprocess_node and code away.